# How to specify SPACE as thousand separater in GWT NumberFormat

Tags: java, gwt

How to specify SPACE as thousand separater in GWT NumberFormat.

I am using GWT's NumberFormat class to format my numbers.
Have a req to separate 1000 with SPACE. Can't get around it so need help.

So 1000000000 should be 1000 000 000.00

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is due to localization, then you might simply need to choose the appropriate locale.

Using *fr* as an example:

```
<extend-property name="locale" value="fr" />
<set-property name="locale" value="fr" />
<set-property-fallback name="locale" value="fr" />
```

Comment: No its not because of localization, we have to disply like this only